# "Jobs near you" uses wrong location

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

The "Jobs near you" section in the right-hand column seems to use the location that is provided by my Internet provider and not the location that I have set manually in my profile.

Although I guess that most of the time these two would match, right now for me there is a pretty big difference as I am located near Malaga, Spain, while I see job ads for Barcelona where the mobile phone operator is located that I am using for my Internet connection.

Shouldn't the manually set location of a user take preference over the location provided by the Internet provider?

Comment: @KevinBrown I'm not sure I agree, the question you linked to has no answers at all and the question mentioned in the comments below it links to a question on another site that does not really asks for it to be changed / a feature request.

Comment: It's marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign], which usually means that there was a reason for now making it customizable. There are quite a few cross-site duplicates about it, I'd recommend checking the [careers tag on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/careers) for many similar questions. You can do a finer grained search on [Careers.SE itself](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/), which takes your manually set location into account.

Comment: @KevinBrown Thanks, I read that somewhere as well. I think it's a fault by design, especially if you are not actively looking but might just be interested when something interesting pops up near you. Right now the whole box is just wasting space, at least for me.

Comment: Not necessary an **exact duplicate**.