# Way to change location for SO Careers ads (sidebar)?

Tags: support, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I use a VPN sometimes, and so the sidebar ads I see for SO Careers job postings are all for jobs in and around the location where the VPN is hosted, rather than my actual current location.

Is there some way to override this, to specify an explicit location (or zip code at least) so that the jobs I see are near my location?

It seems [others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287110/jobs-near-you-uses-wrong-location) have [had](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284035/does-so-careers-not-know-my-location) the [same issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134567/careers-adverts-on-stack-overflow). **I'm looking for a way to override the default IP-based location detection.** Yes, I know I can use the search feature on SO Careers; I'm not actively looking for a job, but it's nice to passively know what's available, so having relevant ads would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've recently added [match preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272492/is-it-possible-to-add-position-level-to-career-profile/272496#272496) which allow you to customise how the jobs tab finds jobs for you... The location data used by that feature is not *currently* consumed by our ad server.

But it is on the backlog and will be implemented in the near future.

Comment: This is a crippling bug that makes ads useless to me.  Every ad I see is near my current employer's headquarters -- far, far away.  I've said in my preferences what regions I prefer but still 100% of the ads I see are for this area of California.    This bug should be elevated and fixed now.