# Can I control the place in the jobs ads in the sidebar?

Tags: support, sidebar, stack-overflow-jobs

I have set my job preferences through my profile->Edit Profile & Settings-> Job Preferences to *not* include my current location, but only a specific single location.

It has effect when I visit the Activity tab on my profile, and the Job Recommendations are only from the desired location. But who checks there anyway? Not a guy that is not actively looking..

I am talking about this:

[image]

It uses my current location, while I am not interested in that, how to help the system target me better?

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Way to change location for SO Careers ads (sidebar)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314433/6083675) — the answer seems to be no, not right now.

Comment: I had seen that @Laurel, but it's 2019 now, so I wondered whether something changed from 2016...