# Use location mentioned in profile for job adverts

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I'd like this feature to be present so the job ads that come up in SO are actually relevant to me and not just wasting my screen space.

It's great that SO jobs uses the IP address to provide jobs in that location but wouldn't it be better if it did this only if your location was not mentioned on your profile and gave a higher priority to the profile location? Or maybe, even have a location property just for jobs. I think this would benefit a lot of people and you could do things like look at jobs available in a location you plan to shift to in a while without having to do things like incorrectly set your location.

It's frustrating viewing a job ad while you're answering/asking questions on SO, thinking 'hey that looks like a great job' only to then realize it's ~1000 kms from where you're staying.

I've seen this ["Jobs near you" uses wrong location](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287110/jobs-near-you-uses-wrong-location) which has no answers and has (in my opinion) been incorrectly labelled as an exact duplicate of [Does SO Careers not know my location?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284035/does-so-careers-not-know-my-location). I'd initially assumed it was a bug and had asked this question ([Stack Overflow Jobs widget showing jobs in different city](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327902/stack-overflow-jobs-widget-showing-jobs-in-different-city)) which I now realize has already been asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bret already mentioned this in his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327960/871146) to your bug report:

> Respecting user location preferences has been in our backlog for a while, but keeps getting bumped for other experiments. The good news is that the experiment backlog is finally almost empty, so there's a good chance we'll get to it as soon as next week.

So I've marked this as [status-planned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-planned). Hopefully the ad server team will get to it in the near future!

Comment: September 2016 and it still does not seem to be implemented. I have my location configured in my profile and my jobs profile, but still the jobs show up based on my IP (which in some Geo IP DBs is incorrectly pointing to Nottingham or London and in some DBs correctly to the Netherlands).

Comment: Jan. 2017 and nothing happened. It's annoying enough that this box can't be deactivated, but even then, it shows me jobs from different countries. A waste of space and a big annoyance.

Comment: What @Bevor said.

Comment: When I met Stack Overflow people at exhibitions or events they told me their main source of income is SO Careers. Why then does this feature have so little priority?

Comment: Still nothing, an active annoyance to many. This should really be implemented. Can't be such a huge chunk of work, either.

Comment: @Pekka웃 the ad server team is pretty small and they’ve been focused on other projects. Sadly that means this feature keeps getting punted. Horia just mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357355/jobs-matching-for-specified-current-location-for-users-behind-proxy#comment518935_357355) that he has code for it so it’s just a case of gluing it all together and making sure it works.

Comment: Nov 2018, I am still seeing job posting for jobs over 2000 miles from my preferred locations in my job search profile. What kind of timeline are we looking at?