# Use location in "Where you'd like to work" from "Job match preferences" user settings to select job adverts

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

Currently, almost all my job adds are from the same country as my IP, even if I specify 3 countries different form my current country in the "Where you'd like to work" under https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/USERID

Can you show more ads based on those preferences if they are set? I'm interested in monitoring the market in those places.

I believe this is different from [Use location mentioned in profile for job adverts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327975/use-location-mentioned-in-profile-for-job-adverts) which talks about the publicly visible location shown on the user profile.

Comment: Congrats for passing the 100k milestone, Ciro!

Comment: @iBug thanks! Now I just have to pass the 1M USD net worth one hehe

Answer (score 3):

We aren't currently picking up your location preferences for serving job recommendations. We have plans to do so in the future, though I can't give an exact date for that.

Comment: This would be hugely useful. I'm looking to move from my current location and intentionally unchecked "Always include your current location" hoping to not see recommendations for my current location, but those are the *only* ones I see.

Comment: Currently I'm *only* getting ads for jobs in neighboring countries; mainly Germany, the Netherlands, Sweden, the UK and Poland.