# Job ads not changing to the city I'm relocating to

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I am a software developer living in XYZ city. I intend to move to ABC city in the coming weeks. I would like to see ABC city job recommendations based on my experience in the sidebar so I have set my profile to show me jobs in that city. I have performed searches in that city, and I even changed my current location to ABC.

I still see recommendations for XYZ in the sidebar. What's the deal? How can I fix this?

Edit: I was giving the cities a nickname to keep the question general for other searchers but since someone has asked:

XYZ = Columbus, Ohio

ABC = Las Vegas, Nevada

Edit #2: I just visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833590/gitlab-runner-ssh-upload-to-server) and this is what my sidebar looks like:
[image]

Comment: I just learned that [job preferences aren't being used in ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/347877/920295)... although there are plans to change this

Comment: When I use my work's vpn, I see job ads for companies at the endpoint of the vpn, not my current location.  Perhaps your IP is being used to locate you for those ads?

Comment: You could use a proxy or VPN in the city you're locating to? Not ideal but if you can't update it in prefences seems like the only option.

Comment: @g3rv4: Is it just me or is that fairly fundamental? So SE is serving job ads entirely untargeted, or is there some other criterion?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wouldn't know the exact details of how ads are targeted (I don't work in that team). What I do know: employers choose the regions they want to show their ads on. Tags you don't want to work with are never included in the ads shown to you. Your activity is weighted to show you more relevant jobs. For more details, do a search of previous questions and if none answer your question, write a new one with the [meta-tag:advertising] tag

Comment: @g3rv4: Okay sounds like it's endpoint based then, thanks