# Why have I been seeing lots of job ads from Germany recently?

Tags: support, advertising, stack-overflow-jobs

Example:

[image]

The number of job ads from Germany has increased over the last few weeks. Is there any way to disable job ads where the position isn't UK based?

Comment: Your question title  should be _How to disable job ads by location_ or similar instead of  _Why have I been seeing lots of job ads from Germany recently_

Comment: This is another example of why the title textbox should be under the question editor, not above it.

Comment: Related? [Use location in “Where you'd like to work” from “Job match preferences” user settings to select job adverts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347874/2821954), [Use location mentioned in profile for job adverts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327975/2821954)

Comment: Germany has currently the issue that they dont have enogh Developers.

Comment: @m4gn1f1c4nt interessting. But all my applications did not succeed or were not read last month. It has to fit a lot. The companies seem (unreasonably?) demanding . yes i am living in germany