# Can you change the jobs advert to include more contextual information on the location, such as postcode?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

In the job advert box, would it be possible to include more detail on the location? As an example, this was the job ads I saw this morning:

[image: Job ad box]

I'll be honest, I had to go to Wikipedia to find out where [Talgarth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talgarth) was, but had I been able to see the first half of the UK postcode (or the first 5 digits of a US ZIP code, the first half of an [Eircode](https://www.eircode.ie/what-is-eircode), the [first two digits of a postal code in the Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_the_Netherlands), etc.) I would have known that it was nowhere near me.

By showing this (partial) postal code information, this actually solves two problems - both dealing with unfamiliar place names are replaced by something that can quickly tell someone if the area is local to their area of interest, even if the place name isn't familiar; and also the fact that places like London are a massive beast, where someone in Reading might find Ealing (W5, London) commutable at about 40 minutes, but maybe not Canary Wharf (E14, London) - about an hour's commute in each direction.

Comment: Isn't that just exchanging one set of unknowns for another? In the London example it means I have to have knowledge of all London postcodes to make a guess as to whether I could travel somewhere. I have no idea where some SW and NW postcodes actually are, had to go look them up in [Google](https://www.doogal.co.uk/images/london_postcode_map.gif). I'm sure other countries have similar issues.

Comment: @Dean I think this would solve more problems than it would create. For Spain, it would solve the issue that in the case of suburbs of major cities it is apparently standard to use the name of the suburb rather than the greater metropolitan area they are located in. For example. it is very hard to tell for a foreigner that [Alcobendas](https://goo.gl/maps/eycr4xEVYko) is part of greater Madrid. Yet I see job ads in Alcobendas all the time. I can confirm the postcode would provide meaningful info in Germany and Finland, too. And in London you at least get a reliable rough idea, no?

Comment: Perhaps taking Horia's suggestion of telling you the distance a job is away from you and then taking into account average commute times (there are data sources for this) we could say "40 mins away"?

Comment: @DeanWard Adding commute time would be market leading, but would require people to have set their commuting preference (mass transit/driving/cycle), as well as having accurate location in their profiles. Does also raise the point that I'd be open to all three of those, but would be happier with a 15 minute walk or cycle, than a 15 minute drive...

Comment: @DeanWard I don't see the swapping unknown for unknown as a problem, as I'm suggesting to add it as *additional* information. Birmingham is actually a worse example, as it's not obvious that B27 is next B92 (illustrating your point), but if I lived around there, *and have an interest in local jobs* I might have that local knowledge

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't think the average person does have detailed knowledge of even the local postcodes. I live in Clapham Junction (SW11) and I didn't know until I just Googled it that SW4 is Clapham Common (a five minute walk from my house). Based on the numbers they shouldn't be adjacent!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson But you'd know that SW represents South West London, and if you saw something for E20, that you'd have a different commute. Ironically, London probably has the better knowledge of postal districts, as they're on the road signs. I appreciate that my experience from working in the logistics sector gives me an advantage on knowing postal areas, but I think most people have an idea at least of the postal are they live in, and currently work in. In my view (and that doesn't mean I'm right) I can see that if this could be added, this gives more detail for people where this matters.

Comment: @RowlandShaw my expectation would be that "if you lived around there" you would know the names of local places. not knowing things about a place you don't live near is a problem with both place names *and* postal codes.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, this just doesn't seem very sensible.  1 - the "first part of postcode" thing is only vaguely relevant in (certain parts of) the UK and is totally, utterly meaningless in every other part of the planet, so completely forget that.  (Don't even mention that, _in the UK_, nobody at all has the slightest clue about postcodes.)  2 - note that even if it used some analog something like, say for the USA, the "County" (sort of a subdivision of "States" there), as everyone else has said, only a few "trainspotter" types have the slightest, vague, clue where "counties" are.  :O

Comment: Here, postcodes have no relevance what so ever. You could put *any* random digits as the post code; this is because mail delivery is done primarily by courier, mailboxes (which are still only available at the central post office) ran out over 40 years ago, and mail here is notoriously unreliable. So yeah, hardly a universal solution.

Comment: @Fattie I did mention a few of the countries where postcodes are hierarchical. I also think it's a little unfair to say *nobody* has the slightest clue about postcodes (and in fact, I'd say it would be a prerequisite to work at [some](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?q=logistics) [companies](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?q=esri))

Comment: When was the last time someone asked you to go and visit the NG21 area? Or when was the last time someone said shall we go see where Robin Hood came from at Sherwood Forest in Edwinstowe Nottinghamshire? Unless your a postman or delivery driver, and even then you probably just rely on your sat nav, you likely have no clue where NG21 is, but an idea on Nottinghamshire.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder And that's kinda my point; in the example I had, I had no idea where Talgarth was - it *could've* been a small town in the area I live in (but did not grow up in), but had I seen straight away that it was LD3, I would know that it's nowhere near me.

Comment: @RowlandShaw How would you have? I know I personally don't memorise all the post codes around me. I don't even know the post codes for the major towns around me. I only know the ones where I live/lived and work. I work in a different postcode area to where I live as well so that also wouldn't help me. I.e. I live in the `NG` area and work in the `S` area. Yet that is only 15 minutes away, yet seeing the postcode I wouldn't have had a clue before working here. Yet hearing the town name I knew the rough area easily.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Similarly, I wouldn't know where Edwinstone is, but could take a good guess that NG21 was somewhere near Nottingham. Another example was Bures, which I'd never heard of (even thought he Royal Mail treat it as a post town), but if I saw that it had a CO8 postcode, I would've known it was near where I studied at University.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I understand your point I'm just saying most people know names rather than codes. And if they do know codes it's either because they're easily guessable or they have knowledge of that place. I think it would be better to post something like: `Edwinstowe, Nottinghamshire` than `NG21` i.e. the place name and surrounding area/county.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That might be a useful alternative (and also solves the [Ashford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashford) issue), but could ignite debate over *which* counties to show (e.g. is Bath in Avon, North East Somerset, or (just) Somerset? or is Ashford in Surrey, or Middlesex?)

Comment: @RowlandShaw They are in where the job ad specifies them, everyone writes their address differently, use a fixed form with the "normal" fields and whatever they put in County (or whatever it will be called) just add that onto the end of the place.

Comment: Of course, if the [ads showed jobs near me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327975/50447), the point would be moot

Comment: @RowlandShaw Or even as Horia answers if it showed "x miles away"

Answer (score 8):

Speaking for the ads team, we *could* show this information, if it were easily available to us. However, AFAIK, we don't extract it in any meaningful way for now. We have a freeform field for the job's address, which we then resolve to a city and country.

As a product issue, postcodes are meaningful in the UK, and with enough experience one can figure out the general area for it by inspecting the first digits. However, that's not the case everywhere. In some countries it's unusual to use a postcode rather than the exact address, while in others the postcodes are hard to parse by humans.

Perhaps it would be more useful to show something like "xx miles away from you", though we do strive to show geographically relevant ads, so you wouldn't see 1000 miles away from you that often, except when there's relocation or remote work involved.

Comment: From my experience, postal codes for countries fall into general categories - geographically hierarchical (including the UK, Ireland, Netherlands, France, Canada), and non-hierachical (So 5 digit US Zipcodes), and none/non-geographic. I'm suggesting that context would be useful where present at least for the geographically hierarchical locales

Comment: Dude, in the very few countries which have this they're not in the slightest geographically "hierarchical".  They're meaningless random letter pairs.  Sure, there are two? three? postcodes that everyone everywhere knows ("90210" and "SW1") .. it's just a nonstarter!  :O

Comment: @RowlandShaw: US Zipcodes are predominantly hierarchical.  Not amazing precision, but moreso than the state.

Comment: @BenVoigt or in other words, showing the postcode provides additional information for the vast majority of the target markets for Stack Overflow :)

Comment: But that's the problem `with enough experience one can figure out the general area for it by inspecting the first digits`. You need experience for working out a postcode and even then you're probably working off your idea of where a county is. Just easier to show the place and county or other containing area than a postcode.

Comment: Yuck! Imperial system units.